# Android Bluetooth Wiimote

Tags: android, bluetooth, wiimote, wii

I'm new to Bluetooth development, and my knowledge is pretty much all accumulated from developers.android.com. I am very familiar with IP TCP sockets, and it looks like Bluetooth takes on the same structure.

What I am looking for, is once a connection to the WIIMote is made, how do I parse data from it? Is there a standard way that the wiimote represents its accelerometer data? Is there a standard way to send data to the LED lights? Is there a simplistic way to send audio to the speaker? Or does it need to be parsed into some form of binary?

Comment: While I never tried to connect a Wiimote to Android, a quick search led to this site: http://wiibrew.org/wiki/Wiimote#Summary

Comment: I looked into the Wii homebrew forums, and it gets really confusing. Starts talking about something called a HID... In short, I can't make any sense of it.

Comment: HID is a Bluetooth profile: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bluetooth_profiles and something related that I found via searching: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263101/how-to-talk-to-a-bluetooth-keyboard/7838587#7838587