# Using Selfie Stick to Launch application

Tags: android, bluetooth, keyboard, hid

I purchased a selfie stick remote that uses Bluetooth to connect to my android device under an HID profile as a keyboard. When I press the button on the selfie stick my android devices registers keycode 66(enter) down and up, and keycode 24(volume down) down and up.

My goal is to create a background service that listens for the selfie stick button to be pressed and launch the app. While doing research for this, I came across [this forum post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263101/how-to-talk-to-a-bluetooth-keyboard) . The post states that "All normal Bluetooth keyboards implement the HID profile, which requires an L2CAP connection. Android so far only provides the ability to use RFCOMM connections. You would need to use the Native Development Kit and write your keyboard code in C to using bluez to achieve your goal. "

The post is five years old now and my question is: Is it [now] possible to intercept Bluetooth HID communications without using NDK.

Answer (score 0):

Most modern Android phones supports Bluetooth low energy (since Bluetooth 4.0), so you could use the [HID Over GATT Profile](https://developer.bluetooth.org/TechnologyOverview/Pages/HOGP.aspx). It uses GATT rather than RFCOMM. Has been supported since [KitKat](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/kitkat.html).